# TABLEAU FILTERS AND SERVERS

Tags: tableau-api

There is an automated report on Tableau server set to run each business day. When we open the report, the filters are still present, but there are no results (no data, no viz). There are also no errors. What are some of the possible explanations for why there would not be data present in the report?  How to Describe to check for each possible explanation?

2.Tableau reports that connect to multiple servers. Assume that one of the servers went down, it’s unclear when it will be back online, and that this server is the most widely used data source. What to do immediately to minimize the impact on business customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lucky that question is not closed normally these type of questions are not entertained in SO

> 1. There are no errors and no data

Since filters are present in reports possible reason would be filters are active on the report are not fetching any data to report hence you are getting blank report and no errors. For E.g if you run the report for emp ID 100 and there is no emp id with number 100 then no data is fetched from database and report will be black.

So possible debug way would be check the applied filters and check in database if there is any data for those filters and if database access is not provided then provided different values for the same report and check data.

> 2. one of the servers went down, it’s unclear when it will be back online

Normally in a live scenario there will be back up servers when primary server is down you need to connect to the back server and minimize the impact and check for the solution for primary server to back online ASAP